# Kill Event when hover off in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, kill

I've seen this somewhere before but I can't seem to find the little snippet.

If I have a div that sets opacity (or animates up) on hover, but I hover off that div before its done animating, I want it to toggle back. Otherwise I hover over it a few times and I have 10+ seconds of animation/flashing to wait for.

Here is my code:

```
$("a.prev").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("normal", 0.6); 
},function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("normal", .1); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stop()`:

```
$("a.prev").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 0.6); 
},function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", .1); 
});
```

Comment: Thank a lot, knew it was something simple!